# Mouse flickering after fresh install

Tags: mouse, display, cursor, flicker

I'm having quite an annoying problem. Just this morning I installed Ubuntu (alongside windows) and I immediately noticed that my cursor is flickering. I searched through askubuntu.com and I found that I needed to either disable the "Unknown display" (Not appearing in my case) or one of the two I currently have. The problem is that I need both of my displays. So, is there anything else I can do to fix this? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

At the blinking cursor, just hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, and lo and behold, you will get a login prompt. From there you will be able to build a working xorg and get xbmc up and running.

Else,

Try holding down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while booting the machine. Keep holding it down until you get the `Grub menu` - hopefully. You'll want to edit the first entry. The next to last line usually, that starts with `linux /boot/vmlinuz-blah blah blah`, and probably ends with **quiet splash**. what ever the line ends with, insert a space followed by `nomodeset`

then boot the machine, read instructions at bottom of that page.

Good Luck, hopefully holding down <kbd>shift</kbd> key will get you into the grub menu.
the `nomodeset` option is used for Nvidia graphics, other graphics need variations on the nomodeset switch. Look at the thread above if necessary.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your quick response. Now, as far as your first paragraph is concerned, I have absolutely no idea what either of these two is. I have some basic understanding of C and I know the very basic linux commands (cd, ls, etc), but other than that I'm a complete and utter newbie when it comes to linux. As for the second paragraph, I have an amd GPU so I'm guessing nomodset wouldn't work. You mentioned a "thread above". I wouldn't know what you meant.

Comment: At any rate, I'd like to thank you again and I hope that you will find the time to answer my - extremely stupid, I'm sure - questions.